# Google app engine is renaming my files while downloading using python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have written a download handler and it is working fine. But the problem is that it is downloading files with the name "download" and for the next time it becomes "download (1)" and so on. Like this:
[image]
I want it to be downloaded with its actual name.
This is my code for download handler:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
import functions

class DownloadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self):
        filename = self.request.get('file_name')
        file_object = functions.getFileList(filename)
        self.send_blob(file_object.blob)
```

and this is the code for the function getFileList():

```
def getFileList(file_name):
    currentUser = getCurrentUser()
    directoryList = getDirectoryList()
    path = getFilePath(file_name, directoryList)
    fileID = currentUser.key.id() + path
    fileKey = ndb.Key(File, fileID)
    return fileKey.get()
```

the flow involved in this function is:

> -getCurrentUser(): This return the current user id of the logged-in user.
>
> -getDirectoryList(): This return a directory object in which we have a list of directories.
>
> -getFilePath(): This will return the file path which is userId+directoryPath+filename.
>
> E.g: 185804764220139124118/New Doc 2019-03-07 03.23.46_1.jpg

and this is the call to main.py from the HTML file:

```
<td class="table_data icon_row">
       <a href="/download?file_name={{ file }}" class="table_link"><span class="material-icons button">file_download</span></a>
</td>
```

and main.py is sending it to downloadhandler.py as

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
[
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/upload', UploadHandler),
    ('/download', DownloadHandler)
], debug=True)
```

The code of download handler is given above.

How to download the files with their actual names.

**Note: The file names on data store are actual but there is some problem with the downloading only.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `save_as` parameter to change the behavior, when `True` it uses the filename of the blob.

```py
self.send_blob(file_object.blob, save_as=True)
```

See ["webapp Blobstore Handlers"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/webapp/blobstorehandlers) for more details.

Comment: hey! I have already tried this but I'm getting an error.

ValueError: Expected BlobInfo value for blob_key_or_info.

I can give you the complete trackback of error as well. But the character limitation here in comments is not letting me do so.